# How to Change Magento Media Path?

Tags: magento-1.9, image, media

Is it possible to change the image source path in the media folder:

From:

```
www.example.com/media/catalog/category/apple-iphonex.jpg
```

To:

```
www.example.com/apple/media/apple-iphonex.jpg
```